# Query the post which have a thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, query, thumbnails

I've got a highlight section on the header of my website which shows the title and the thumbnail of the last X posts having a thumbnail.

Is there any custom query which allows me to retrieve only the last X post having a thumbnail?

At the moment I'm retrieving the last X * 10 posts (because not all the posts have a thumbnail) hoping that in this result I'll have X posts having a thumbnail. After doing my query I add a condition: `if (has_post_thumbnail())`.

This solution is really uncertain and ugly, a custom query with a thumbnail parameter would be great but I couldn't find any hint about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to work this into your query: `'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters